# How to use parameterized style?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I haven't read the documentation.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}
\tikzset
{
    helper/.style={color=#1!50,line width=#2},
    helper/.default={blue,12pt}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[helper] (0,0) -- (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How to use parameterized style?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must explicitly define the number of parameters the style will take, as in `helper/.style 2 args={...}`.

Additionally, comma-separated lists are not supported here. So you must do `helper/.default={blue}{12pt}` for your example above. The same syntax should be used when actually applying parameters to the style.

Here's an example based on your M(n)WE:

**The Code**

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}
\tikzset
{
    helper/.style 2 args={color=#1!50,line width=#2},
    helper/.default={blue}{12pt},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[helper={red}{2pt}] (0,0) -- (2,2);
    \draw[helper] (2,0) -- (0,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**The Output**

[image]